# Does Microsoft Provides a PKCS #11 provider that connects to its own MS CryptoAPI?

Tags: cryptoapi, pkcs#11, mscapi

I'm looking to run some tests using the PKCS #11 interface and was wondering if Microsoft provided a software based implementation the provides PKCS #11 functionality?

Rather then waiting for a HSM to arrive and be properly configured I'd rather get started on testing interaction with the interface now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft does not. Microsoft has rejected PKCS11 in favor of the smart card minidriver/base smart card CSP. However, you can get smart cards with PKCS11 support from many vendors that will allow you to test code. Some even have "softtokens" that emulate a smart card. Note that most smartcards are quite limited as to what they support relative to a full HSM.

Answer (score 0):

It´s not provided by Microsoft but you can use third parties implementations, for example:

- [p11-capi](https://github.com/risacher/p11-capi)
- [pvpkcs11](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/pvpkcs11)